# React admin: Confirm message on route switch

Tags: react-admin

I want to prevent users from leaving `CreateVacancy` component by warning them about unsaved changes.

Dealing with `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` via redux saga is of little help, because action is already dispatched and page switch will happen anyways.

Difficulty with React Admin is that I don't have access to `<Route/>` component directly. Otherwise I would use Route's `onLeave` prop to achieve my goal.

I need to somehow track previous location (`/vacancy/create`) and prevent users from leaving to any other route without `confirm`ing.

What would you recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be a great feature request. Can you create one on our repository? In the mean time, as we use `react-router`, you can probably leverage its [`Prompt`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Prompt) component:

```
import { Prompt } from 'react-router';

const PostCreate = props => (
    <Fragment>
          <Prompt message="Are you sure you want to leave?" />
          <Create {...props}>
              ...
          </Create>
    </Fragment>
)
```

I haven't tested it but it should work. If you need to customize the dialog further, have a look at this [article](https://kamranicus.com/posts/2018-07-26-react-router-custom-transition-ui)